# How to determine if an Android device is compromised with a rootkit?

Tags: security, malware

How would you go about checking your smartphone for root level malware, including rootkits, if you cannot get direct access to smartphone partitions?

There's news almost monthly how cheap Android phones or even Android smart TVs contain malware. And then devices invariably stop being updated (some come without updates at all), and people continue to happily use them, while their e.g. Linux kernel is rife with local root exploits.

Comment: Hello. I've edited your question and removed the part concerning Google. We can't tell why Google did or does something. You are free to search  Google's press releases, its developers comments on various forums and so on to figure out the reason. It would all be opinions that we can provide (and a question that seeks opinions is off-topic here). I've therefore removed the off-topic part. Aside from that, you might get better suggestions at [security.se] than here.

Comment: I'm in secops and I don't know the answer other than trying to exploit a root vulnerability which is usually available for old unsupported devices. You've removed a very important part of the question which is "oem unlock erases user data". That's a way in, along with unlocking boot loader and using e.g magisk or/and TWRP but too often undesired for obvious reasons.

Comment: oem unlock does not erase user data - bootloader unlock does. this is for privacy protection. I don't believe in rootkits, simple factory reset will remove possible malware

Comment: Rootkit can remount the system partition in read write mode and plant whatever it desires.

Comment: no. dm-verity prevents that.

Comment: You seem to be right https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot but I wonder if Google can really enforce it on all Android vendors and then there's a question of ROMs which come with malware preinstalled by the OEM itself.

Comment: preinstalled malware by OEM is not malware. that's a opinion-based definition of [malware](https://www.gnu.org/proprietary/malware-google.html.en). I don't know of any other method to check for other than analyzing the traffic. if you don't like it, don't use stock ROM

Comment: If the malware has modified system partition you can safely unlock bootloader - as user data erase does not modify system partition you can then simply access the malware for analyzing it. And if the ROM was infected with malware you can also unlock bootloader to get root access and extracting the firmware.